# Intellij - No maven module

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I was trying to create a new project in intelliJ using maven module but notice that it has disappear. I tried google but can't find a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to enable Maven Integration in your plugins.

[image]